# Передача аргументов в компоненты React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

в **Main.jsx** задана переменная через `useState()`

```
const[foo, setFoo] = useState([])
```

Дальше я передаю сеттер в **Component1.jsx**, а саму переменную в **Component2.jsx**, в нем я отрисовываю на основе полученного массива разметку.

По какой то причине когда я обновляю переменную через сеттер который я передал в первый компонент, я не получаю информацию о обновлении переменной во втором компоненте и моя разметка не ререндерится, хотя другие переменные работают по такому же принципу, не могу понять в чем может быть проблема, потому что другие переменные по такому же принципу у меня работают

**Main.jsx**

```
function Main() {
    const[foo, setFoo] = useState([])

    return (
    <>
        <div className="Main">
            <Component1  setFoo={setFoo}/>
            <Component2 foo={foo}/>
        </div>
    </>
    );
}

export default Main;
```

**Component1.jsx**

```
function Component1({setFoo}) {
    setFoo([{id: 5}, {id: 8}])
    return (
    <>
        <div className="Component1">
            
        </div>
    </>
    );
 export default Component1
```

**Component2.jsx**

```
function Component2({foo}) {
    console.log(foo) // Этот код срабатывает только при первой загрузке и после перерендера (когда обновляешь код, сюда доходит новая переменная)
    return (
    <>
        <div className="Component2">
            {foo.map(card =>{
                return(
                    <div>
                       {card.id}
                    </div>
                )})
             }
        </div>
    </>
    );
}

export default Component2
```

Comment: Если вы хотите повысить шанс на хороший ответ, то добавьте больше кода.

Comment: @OliverPatterson добавил, описал проблему более подробно в комментариях около кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя  изменять переменную с useState напрямую(хотел изменить переменную через push и потом ее же передать в сеттер), после этого не происходит перерендера

Comment: В приведенном вами коде, данных манипуляций - нет.

Answer (score 1):

> По какой то причине когда я обновляю переменную через сеттер который я передал в первый компонент, я не получаю информацию о обновлении переменной во втором компоненте и моя разметка не ререндерится

Если все сделать нормально - все будет рендериться. В твоих кусках кода, что ты привел, не особо понятно что ты там делаешь...

```js
//
function Main() {
    const[foo, setFoo] = React.useState([])

    return (
      <div className="Main">
          <Component1 setFoo={setFoo} />
          <Component2 foo={foo} />
      </div>
    );
}
//
function Component1({setFoo}) {
  const action = _ => setFoo(old => [...old, {id: Math.random()}])
  return (
    <div className="Component1">
      <button onClick={action}>Добавить</button>
    </div>
  );
}
//
function Component2({foo}) {
    return (
        <div className="Component2">
            {foo.map(card => <div key={card.id}>{card.id}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<Main />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Comment: я уже ниже ответил в чем была причина, код показал для наглядности куда и что передаю, ты написал абсолютно такой же код что и приведен у меня, ноль различия